# Your application is still a FATAL WARNING. Still ERROR!

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

Your application is still a FATAL WARNING. What is it about. I don't keep money there, don't use it. Comodo removes your app without asking. I see messages that RiskWare from Malwarebytes.
log frag.

2021-06-15 20:59:57.195 5920    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2021-06-15 20:59:57.195 5920    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:412   Logging to "C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\monero-wallet-gui\monero-wallet-gui.log"
2021-06-15 21:00:00.269 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'asa' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.269 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'ave' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.270 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'boa' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.270 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'cal' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.271 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'dar' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.272 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'don' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.272 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'dos' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.272 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'eco' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.272 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'eje' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.273 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'fax' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.273 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'feo' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.273 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'fin' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.274 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'gen' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.274 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'gol' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.274 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'haz' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.275 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'ira' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.276 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'luz' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.276 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'mar' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.276 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'mes' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.276 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'mil' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.277 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'oca' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.277 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'ojo' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.277 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'ola' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.278 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'oro' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.278 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'oso' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.278 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'pan' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.281 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'pez' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.281 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'pie' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.282 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'red' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.283 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'res' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:00:00.283 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   Español word 'rey' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2021-06-15 21:03:38.173 5920    ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   shellItem: SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:///C:/Users/123/Documents/Monero/wallets)) failed (The system cannot find the path specified.)
2021-06-15 21:03:38.180 5920    ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   shellItem: SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:///C:/Users/123/Documents/Monero/wallets)) failed (The system cannot find the path specified.)
2021-06-15 21:04:12.290 5920    ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   shellItem: SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:///C:/Users/123/Documents/Monero/wallets)) failed (The system cannot find the path specified.)
2021-06-15 21:04:12.291 5920    ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   shellItem: SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:///C:/Users/123/Documents/Monero/wallets)) failed (The system cannot find the path specified.)
2021-06-15 21:05:33.903 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   EnglishOld word 'out' is shorter than its prefix length, 4

2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: wond
2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: atte
2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: birt
2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: perf
2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: cons
2021-06-15 21:05:33.915 5920    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132   EnglishOld word 'egg' is shorter than its prefix length, 4

2023-08-02 10:46:38.333 6376    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148   Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
2023-08-02 12:20:48.372 6368    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 12:20:48.372 6368    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   Logging to "C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\monero-wallet-gui\monero-wallet-gui.log"
2023-08-02 12:20:48.375 6368    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:259:9: QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2023-08-02 12:23:41.598 6368    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 12:23:41.972 8424    ERROR   wallet.ringdb   src/wallet/ringdb.cpp:225   dbr. THROW EXCEPTION: tools::error::wallet_internal_error
2023-08-02 12:23:42.039 8424    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:7704 Failed to initialize ringdb: Failed to open rings database file 'C:\ProgramData.shared-ringdb': Input/output error
2023-08-02 12:23:42.296 8424    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:5569 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 43hmxQ6U46THfvKi8NuF6RgjwusSx1qbPKEidc5X628X6KMLuwePoTrQmaUsTFJ9nxfjiWpmXuKGaFBwjvChsVQhJsrxk7j
2023-08-02 23:29:06.482 2812    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 23:29:06.482 2812    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   Logging to "C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\monero-wallet-gui\monero-wallet-gui.log"
2023-08-02 23:29:06.498 2812    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:259:9: QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2023-08-02 23:29:46.661 2812    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 23:29:47.108 6628    ERROR   wallet.ringdb   src/wallet/ringdb.cpp:225   dbr. THROW EXCEPTION: tools::error::wallet_internal_error
2023-08-02 23:29:47.276 6628    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:7704 Failed to initialize ringdb: Failed to open rings database file 'C:\ProgramData.shared-ringdb': Input/output error
2023-08-02 23:29:47.864 6628    WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:5569 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 43hmxQ6U46THfvKi8NuF6RgjwusSx1qbPKEidc5X628X6KMLuwePoTrQmaUsTFJ9nxfjiWpmXuKGaFBwjvChsVQhJsrxk7j
2023-08-02 23:41:48.452 4908    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 23:41:48.452 4908    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   Logging to "C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\monero-wallet-gui\monero-wallet-gui.log"
2023-08-02 23:41:48.452 4908    WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:411   qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/ApplicationWindow.qml:259:9: QML ContentItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2023-08-02 23:41:55.833 4908    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-08-02 23:41:55.920 936 ERROR   wallet.ringdb   src/wallet/ringdb.cpp:225   dbr. THROW EXCEPTION: tools::error::wallet_internal_error
2023-08-02 23:41:55.965 936 ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:7704 Failed to initialize ringdb: Failed to open rings database file 'C:\ProgramData.shared-ringdb': Input/output error
2023-08-02 23:41:56.223 936 WARNING wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:5569 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 43hmxQ6U46THfvKi8NuF6RgjwusSx1qbPKEidc5X628X6KMLuwePoTrQmaUsTFJ9nxfjiWpmXuKGaFBwjvChsVQhJsrxk7j

Comment: Please see the Q&A I linked.